# How to delete sub categories in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to delete all sub categories and their inner categories if I delete the main category ?

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anKRE.png)

Here if I delete the category 'computer' means how to delete their sub categories also (mouse,keyboard,virtual,touch) ?

Comment: your table structure is wrong.. there should be 2 tables `parent table` and `child table`

Comment: Can you please tell the structure ? which will be right for this concept ? I will create unlimited sub categories

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one of the following options to accomplish this:

1- You setup your database to enforce referential integrity, then it's as easy as telling MySQL `ON DELETE CASCADE;`

Note tested, but I guess it should work.

```
ALTER TABLE categories
ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
REFERENCES Categories(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

2- Second option is calling your delete function recursively to accomplish this.
example:

```
public function delete_category_by_id ($category_id) {
    // delete this category.
    $this->db->delete('categories', ['id' => $category_id]);
    // fetch child categories & call the same method again.
    $q = $this->db->where('parent_id', $category_id)->get('categories');
    foreach( $q->result() as $Child ) {
        $this->delete_category_by_id($Child->id);
    }
}
```

This would be very destructive & it might take long time depending on how many levels you have

Answer (score 1):

```
function delete_parent_and_child_subchild($category_id,$all_cate=array())
{
    if(!is_array($category_id))
    {           
        $this->db->where('parent_id', $category_id);
        $all_cate[]=$category_id;
    }
    else
    {           
        $this->db->where_in('parent_id', $category_id);
    }        
    $get_categories= $this->db->get('newcategory'); 
    if($get_categories->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $categories_vales=$get_categories->result(); 
        $new_subcat = array();
        foreach($categories_vales as $cate_val)
        {
            $category_id=$cate_val->category_id;
            array_push($new_subcat,$category_id);
        }
        $all_cate = array_merge($all_cate,$new_subcat);         
        if(count($new_subcat)>0)
        {
            $this->delete_parent_and_child_subchild($new_subcat,$all_cate);
        }   
    }   
    $this->db->where_in('category_id', $all_cate)->delete('newcategory');
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deleting category based on ID, so please store those ID in one variable and again make one another query for delete based on parent_id=ID.

Delete row based on category ID :

```
$SQL = "delete from category where id=9";
```

Delete subcategory based on category ID :

```
$SQL = "delete from category where parent_id=9";
```

OR you can do in one query both condition.

```
$SQL = "delete from category where id=9 or parent_id=9";
```

Comment: if I'm doing like this computer,mouse,keyboard only will delete. What about touch and virtual ? It is also sub category of mouse and keyboard ..

Comment: you want to delete by name and its subcategory also?

Comment: what about this -> `$SQL = "delete from category where name='mouse' or parent_id=(select id from category where name='mouse')";`

Comment: I want to delete not only sub categories of main category. If the subcategory has some category means that is also should be delete. here if i delete computer .. its all sholud be delete ( mouse,keyboard,virtual,touch )

Comment: ok i got it. you have to do recursive function for that in php.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it with single query

```
$query = "delete from category where id=1 or parent_id=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

**parent_table**

```
id  value
1 computer
2 electronics
```

**child_table**

```
child_tbl_pk_id parent_table_id   value
1                     1           mouse
2                     1           touch
3                     2           fan
```

**Queries:**

```
q1 = "DELETE FROM parent_table WHERE id = 1"
q2 = "DELETE FROM child_table WHERE parent_table_id = 1"
```

Comment: If I create another subcategory under 'touch' means Now where will be add the 'touch' ? Its parent_table or child_table ?

Comment: @KrishJothy it'l be in child table

Answer (score 0):

Run this code by passing parent_id() and change table name with your table

```
function delete_parent_and_child_subchild($category_id,$all_cate=array())
{
    if(!is_array($category_id))
    {           
        $this->db->where('parent_id', $category_id);
        $all_cate[]=$category_id;
    }
    else
    {           
        $this->db->where_in('parent_id', $category_id);
    }        
    $get_categories= $this->db->get('newcategory'); 
    if($get_categories->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $categories_vales=$get_categories->result(); 
        $new_subcat = array();
        foreach($categories_vales as $cate_val)
        {
            $category_id=$cate_val->category_id;
            array_push($new_subcat,$category_id);
        }
        $all_cate = array_merge($all_cate,$new_subcat);         
        if(count($new_subcat)>0)
        {
            $this->delete_parent_and_child_subchild($new_subcat,$all_cate);
        }   
    }   
    $this->db->where_in('category_id', $all_cate)->delete('newcategory');
    return true;
}
```